# Let the edges appear in object mode as they do on the edit world (manga style)

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, edges, object-mode

I've been using blender for a while now and I've always wanted to know how to make the edges of the edit mode appear in ibject mode. It can give a bit of a manga style. I've seen that you can add the linearts of the object but that doesn't cover ALL the edges of the edit mode. Does anyone have a solution?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what you mean by "manga style", but does checking <kbd>Wireframe</kbd> on the <kbd>Viewport Overlays</kbd> menu do what you want? - The Cube below is shown in Object mode and has been subdivided a couple of times in <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode.

[image]

Comment: That's with the cube selected of course, the orange lines are black if it's deselected. You can also use View > Viewport Render Image to take a snapshot of that view and then Image > Save Image to save it.

Comment: THANK YOU !!! It's exactly what I wanted !! Just a quick question: is it possible to increase or decrease the thickness of the lines (edges)?

Comment: And a last question :) Is it possible to choose which objects you want to apply this "technique" to, or does it have to be applied to the whole scene?

Comment: Under Preferences > Interface > Display, you can change Line Width from Default to Thick or Thin on the dropdown. I don't think you can use the technique on a single object. It's all or nothing I'm afraid unless anyone else here knows better. Incidentally you can check my answer as correct if you wish.